# In Octave, how to close the serial port after opening with the new "serialport" command syntax

Tags: serial-port, octave

The latest documentation for serial communication in Octave explains to use the "serialport" command to open the port instead of the deprecated "serial" command.

- https://octave.sourceforge.io/instrument-control/overview.html

There is no explanation of how to close the serial port.  I used this to successfully open the port and do some writing

```
s1=serialport('com5','Baudrate',57600)
num=write(s1,'help')
```

But I can't figure out how to close the port.  I used this:

```
fclose(s1)
```

And got this error response

```
error: file id must be a file object, std::string, or integer value
```

Does anyone know how to close the serial port?

Answer (score 0):

The octave functions attempt to mimic where possible the Matlan functions, which also does not have a close function.

To close the serial port, set the variable to something else, and if it is not used elsewhere, it will close the port.

```
# create a serialport references by the s1 variable
s1=serialport('com5','Baudrate',57600)
num=write(s1,'help')

# set s1 to something else
s1 = [];
# s1 was only variable referencing the serial port
# so the serial port is now freed/closed
```

You could also clear the variable:

```
clear s1
```